# Is there any way to save files when switching to a different version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, files, default-programs, installed-programs

Is there any way of saving all the apps that i have downloaded and files in my home folder when switching versions of Ubuntu? I want to upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10 but don't want to lose all of the applications that I have downloaded or the files that have been collected over a period of time. It will take a lot of time and bandwidth if I have to download everything over again. Thanks!

Comment: yes, back them up on an separate device.

Comment: If you can wait 2 months, then 14,04 will be released which is a LTS and you would be able to upgrade straight from 12.04 to 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply upgrade your system, if it's connected to the Internet :

First, verify that a new version exists :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only
```

Then, if you're satisfied with the system proposed, do :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

**ATTENTION** : you have to have enough space on your hard disk to do this upgrade. You won't be advised if you haven't enough free space and the upgrade will fail (and that's not good for your data)

---

Without an Internet connection on the computer where Ubuntu is installed, you can also download a [LiveCD of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and install it, it will ask you if you want to upgrade your current system or if you want to install a new one.

Comment: This doesn't answer the stated question. Please edit your answer.

Comment: nice answer mate

Comment: @Alvar : Spot9901 wants to upgrade his system without loosing his files. That's a way to do it, isn't it ? I could also indicate a way to `grep` the installed-package list, and tell him to install a new system, then apply the list to automatically install all the packages, but that would be taking the hard-road.

Comment: you can't upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10....

Comment: yes, but you can upgrade from 12.04 to 13.04. And then you can upgrade to 13.10

Comment: @MrVaykadji Actually it would be 3 upgrades. 12.10, 13.04 (which has reached End of Life) and 13.10. The easiest solution would be to wait until 14.04LTS comes out and then it's a straight upgrade from 12.04LTS. You can view ubuntu Releases and scheduled releases at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases